# Calculation of Copper Melting

Tags: factorio

[image]

The melter has 30% downtimes, I expect to have 66% downtimes.

What is the calculation base?

1. The steel furnance has a crafting speed of 2 per second.
2. The electric mining drill has a mining speed of 0.5 per second
3. The copper plate has a production time of 3.2 seconds

This means, the steel furnance can melt 1.6 (3.2/2) but 3 times the electic minig drill gives 1.5 (3*0.5) ore per second.

What is the calculation base for melting?

Comment: Why are you multiplying by 3?

Comment: @Corsaka 3 times the electic drill * 0.5

Comment: Yeah, but where is the 3 coming from?

Comment: @Corsaka Ignore that, from my calculations it is the most close value to 1.6

Comment: Yeah, it's completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 9):

Copper has a mining time of 1 second.

Electric mining drill has a mining speed of 0.5.

1/0.5 = **2 seconds per copper ore.**

Steel furnace has a crafting speed of 2.

Copper plate has a production time of 3.2 seconds.

3.2/2 = **1.6 seconds per copper plate.**

This means that there is **0.4 seconds** where the furnace is **not on**, because the furnace is faster than the mining drill.

Sources:
https://wiki.factorio.com/Copper_ore
https://wiki.factorio.com/Mining
https://wiki.factorio.com/Steel_furnace